# android check if GPS already has a fix

Tags: android, gps, location

i have an app that takes the user exact GPS location and save it to a database when he presses a button.

i need his exact location(i.e location that is Fixed with GPS)
i used onLocationChanged() and GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX, but the problem was if the user was standing still and already had a fix, then he pressed a button, the app would wait as it neither of the above will launch.

and i was wondering if there was any way i can check if the GPS already has a fix on the device's location.

Comment: try get accuracy method -- normaly for a gps fix its 20 m so if its less than say 50 no gps fix is there ( you can also check the time of the fix and use ur logic)

Comment: i thought about it but i don't think it's reliable enough !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [android getBestProvider never returns gps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480042/android-getbestprovider-never-returns-gps)